# Javascript/JQuery .each not doing what I want

Tags: jquery

I'm a bit new to jQuery, I've been assigned to do this little thing for my boyfriend. But honestly I'm stuck! Im using a `.join()` and a `.each()` so that I can loop through the `.joined` array, but for some reason it stops on the first obstacles x value even if its not touching?

```
function collides(a, b) {
    var aTop = a.offset().top;
    var aLeft = a.offset().left;
    var bTop = b.offset().top;
    var bLeft = b.offset().left;

    return !(((aTop + a.height()) < (bTop))
    || (aTop > (bTop + b.height()))
    || ((aLeft + a.width()) < bLeft)
    || (aLeft > (bLeft + b.width())));
}
var myArrayOne = ["#secondObs", "#firstObs", "#thirdObs"];
var ObstacleLvlOne = $(myArrayOne.join(', '));

//colliding stuff and response.
function handleCollisions() {
    $.each(ObstacleLvlOne, function (myArrayOne) {
        if (collides($(this), $('#player'))) {
            $('#levelOne').stop();

            $('#player').css('border', 'solid 1px yellow');
        }
    });
```

link: http://jsfiddle.net/38bod36e/69/

Comment: You can't use a .each() on a string, which is what join() returns. Try using .concat to make two arrays one array, if that's what you're trying to do (bit confused on goal)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this, I don't see why you would need to join the array

```
$.each( myArrayOne, function(index,value) {
       console.log(index,value); //0,1,2  "#secondObs", "#firstObs" , "#thirdObs"
if (collides($(value), $('#player'))) {
          $('#levelOne').stop();
          $('#player').css('border', 'solid 1px yellow');
      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but im still having the same problome, it's stopping in clear space not even touching the first Obs? http://jsfiddle.net/38bod36e/70/

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the other answer, first update your $.each usage:

```
$.each(myArrayOne, function (index, value) {
    var $player = $('#player');

    if (collides($(value), $player)) {
        $('#levelOne').stop();
        $player.css('border', 'solid 1px yellow');
    }
});
```

Then make sure all your obstacles exist before you try to check collisions with them. Your code is looking for `#thirdObs` but the jsfiddle you provided (http://jsfiddle.net/38bod36e/70/) does not define its position and size, try removing that from your array until you write the css for it.

This is how it would work: http://jsfiddle.net/38bod36e/72/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `each` and jQuery selectors in such way. Just get your elements by `$` and loop through them by `each` method:

```
$("#secondObs, #firstObs, #thirdObs").each(function () {
    if (collides($(this), $('#player'))) {
        $('#levelOne').stop();
        $('#player').css('border', 'solid 1px yellow');
    }
});
```